How to resolve Android Studio failing to create AVD
Today I updated my Android Studio to the latest version (Jellyfish 2023.3.1 Patch) and I can no longer create virtual devices. The create device process just says "Error Creating AVD, An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details."
From the log the error appears to be the AVD manager can't find the Android SDK installation directory. I looked in Android Studio to find where the SDK is installed and indeed it appears to be installed at that location.
How can I get the AVD Manager to find the SDK?
This is a Windows 11 installation.
